# How to assign array for session variable and store values into database in joomla

Tags: php, session, joomla

I have creating project in joomla, for get user entry from textbox and store into session and session assinged for variables,

I was set session variable , but i dont know how to get and store into database, because the values may be  n Numbers based on user entry

my view is

```
<td><input type="text" name="lmno[]1" id="lmno[]1"   value=""></td>
<td><input type="text" name="pieceno[]1" id="pieceno[]1"  value=""></td>
<td><input type="text" name="aepi[]1" id="aepi[]1"  value=""></td>
<td><input type="text" name="appi[]1" id="appi[]1"  value=""></td>
<td><input type="text" name="awid[]1" id="awid[]1"  value=""></td>
<td><input type="text" name="offermts[]1" id="offermts[]1"  value=""></td>
<td><input type="text" name="passmts[]1" id="passmts[]1"  value=""></td>
<td><input type="text" name="rejmts[]1"  id="rejmts[]1" value=""></td>
<td><input type="text" name="lessmts[]1" id="lessmts[]1" value=""></td>
<td><input type="text" name="points[]1" id="points[]1" value=""></td>
<td><input type="text" name="pts1[]1"  id="pts1[]1" value=""></td>
<td><input type="text" name="remarks[]1" id="remarks[]1"value=""></td>
<td><input type='button' id='addButton' value="Add" >
```

and model code is

```
$data= $app->input->getArray($_POST);
    $session = JFactory::getSession();
    $session->set('lmno', $data['lmno']);
    $session->set('pieceno', $data['pieceno']);
    $session->set('aepi', $data['aepi']);
    $session->set('awid', $data['awid']);
    $session->set('offermts', $data['offermts']);
    $session->set('passmts', $data['passmts']);
    $session->set('rejmts', $data['rejmts']);
    $session->set('lessmts', $data['lessmts']);
    $session->set('points', $data['points']);
    $session->set('pts1', $data['pts1']);
    $session->set('remarks', $data['remarks']);
```

How to these variable value and store into joomla databse

guide me finish this task....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value from the session,

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$lmno    = $session->get('lmno', '');
$pieceno = $session->get('pieceno', '');
```

In order to save to the database using JTable, you can use the following syntax.

```
$row    = JTable::getInstance('User', 'JTable');
if(!$row->save($data)){
    throw new Exception($row->getError(), 500);
}
```